# Adding navigation links based on privillages?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following master page in asp .net:

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="KezberProjectManager.master.cs" Inherits="KezberProjectManager.KezberProjectManager" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <!-- Le styles -->
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        padding-top: 60px; /* 60px to make the container go all the way to the bottom of the topbar */
      }
    </style>
    <!-- Le HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </a>
          <a class="brand" href="#">Test</a>
          <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Calendar</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Boss Stuff</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
       <div class="container">
       <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

       </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
    </div> <!-- /container -->

    </div>
    </form>
      <!-- Le javascript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The navigation is made like this for every page:

```
   <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
          <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </a>
          <a class="brand" href="#">Test</a>
          <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav">
              <li class="active"><a href="#">Calendar</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Boss Stuff</a></li>
              <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

What I cannot figure out is how could I make it so that, if admin is requesting the page, add the Boss Stuff link?

In terms of session management and all that it's all good, I'm able to determine in my code behind if the user is admin, what I do not know is how to add the boss link only if he is admin on page load.

What might be a 'best' or standard practice way to do this?

Thanks

I mean, literally, how do I, from my page load event, add links to my navigation. How do I go from the CS to the aspx?

Comment: Have you tried [UserIsInRole()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms127603.aspx)?

Comment: Thats not my problem. I mean, literally, how do I, from my page load event, add links to my navigation. How do I go from the CS to the aspx?

Comment: I could hackishly add csharp code to my aspx file but I figure there must be a better way.

Comment: What about just putting an `id` and `runat=server` on the `li` for Boss and making its `Visible` based on user role?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using .Net membership, something as simple as this could be done if you want to do it in the page markup:

```
<% if (Page.User.IsInRole("Admin"))
   { %>
       <a href="#">Boss Stuff</a>
 <% } %>
```